# Export datagrid to Excel using Dialog Box on Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, datagrid, export-to-excel

I'm looking for how to export a datagrid (or dataSet) (not datagridview) to Excel using dialog box which saves data in specific place, I am working on VS 2003 Winform not Webform.

This is my code:

I just need too open a dialog box to let the user choose where he wants to put his file:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
#region
                string data = null;
                int i = 0;
                int j = 0; 

                Excel.Application xlApp ;
                Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
                Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
                object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
                xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
                xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

                for (i = 0; i <= dsSelectionListeDiffere.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (j = 0; j <= dsSelectionListeDiffere.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                    {
                        data = dsSelectionListeDiffere.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = data;
                    }
                }

                xlWorkBook.SaveAs("csharp.net-informations.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
                xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
                xlApp.Quit();

                releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
                releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
                releaseObject(xlApp);

                MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file c:\\csharp.net-informations.xls");
#endregion
}
```

and i have another code it works too :

```
#region
////            lblMessage.Visible = true;
////            lblMessage.Text = "";
//          // Export all the details
//          try
//          {           
//              // Get the datatable to export          
//              DataTable dt = dsSelectionListeDiffere.Tables[0].Copy();
//              dsSelectionListeDiffere = FrmFonctionPrincipale.getListeDifferesParClient(1);
//              // Export all the details to Excel
//
//
//              RKLib.ExportData.Export objExport = new RKLib.ExportData.Export("Win");             
//              objExport.ExportDetails(dt, Export.ExportFormat.Excel, "C:\\EmployeesInfo.xls");
//              MessageBox.Show("Exporté Avec Succès dans  C:\\EmployeesInfo.xls");
//          }
//          catch(Exception Ex)
//          {
//              MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
////                lblMessage.Text = Ex.Message;
//          }
        #endregion
```

Comment: Do you need to specify the filename or just the folder where your fixed filename will be created by excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to change the filename, but only the folder where this file is saved, then you can use the [FolderBrowserDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx) to ask just the folder where the file will be saved

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    fbd.Description = "Select the destination folder";
    fbd.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
    fbd.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal;
    if( fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK )
    {
        string folderName = fbd.SelectedPath;
        .... the rest of your excel export code .....

        // Pass the full path to the SaveAs method
        string fullPathName = Path.Combine(folderName, "csharp.net-informations.xls");
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(fullPathName, .....);

        .....

        MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file in: " + fullPathName);
   }
```

If you need to change also the file name, then you need to use a SaveFileDialog instance.

```
 SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
 sfd.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls)|*.xls|All files (*.*)|*.*"  ;
 sfd.FilterIndex = 1 ;
 sfd.RestoreDirectory = true ;
 sfd.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
 if(sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
 {
     if(sfd.FileName.Length > 0)
     {
        ... the rest of your excel code here ....

        // sfd.FileName already contains the full path so
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(sfd.FileName, .....);

     }
 }
 else
 {
      if(MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to quit without saving?", "Quitting",
                         MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
      {
          // This important to stop the Form to close if this button is the Cancel/AcceptButton
          // or its property DialogResult is not DialogResult.None
          this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
      }
 }
```

Comment: `DialogResult result = ??????  ;`
i write what here? :  `xlWorkBook.SaveAs(fullPathName, ??????);`
because i have an error when i write fullPathName as argument because i have alredy just 13 argument the error is : No overload for method 'SaveAs' takes '13' arguments"

Comment: Sorry, a leftover from a copy/paste operation. To be removed

Comment: fullPathName replaces your previous filename "csharp.net-information.xls"

Comment: it work but when i try to export it one more time  a dialogbox appear : "there is already a file with this name" so how can i not replace this file and create another in the same folder please

Comment: If you need to change the filename then you need to use a SaveFileDialog instead of FolderBrowserDialog. You could read about [this class here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx)

Comment: the code you gave me is steel true even when i change to SaveFileDialog , i have juste need to edit this line : 
`fbd.Description = "Select the destination folder";
    fbd.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
    fbd.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal;`
and `string folderName = fbd.SelectedPath;`
?????
thank you

Comment: thank you so muuch it's work exactly like i want thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuu :)

Comment: sorry if i disturb you , i have another thing to do but i don't know how to fixe it : i want where i click the button, the data will not be eported ,but the excel file will be opened with data and the user will choose if he want save it after the analyse or not , hope it's clear :(

Comment: I think that we have diverged too much from the original question. At this point it is better to post a new question and give better opportunities to other people to answer a new and more focused question. Of course you could reference this question for better clarifications and understanding.